# Finding equations for plane figures using complex coordinates

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I have to find conditions defining the following plane figures:

[image: Problem 1-2][image: Problem 3-4]

Where:
$a=3$ and $b=7$

I know that circumference form is:
$$\left |z-z_0 \right | =b$$

So, for c. with center $(3,3)$ and  radius $7$ the equation would be something like: 
$$\left |z-3-3i \right | =7$$

But I don't know how to model the other points.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you trying to find equations for the entire blue shaded area, or just for the perimeter of each figure? The example that you give for (c) is only the equation for the perimeter. Also, perhaps you mean $|z-z_0|=b$, instead of $|z-z_0|=a$?

Comment: You're right is $$\left |z-z_0 \right | =b$$ cause in this case b is my radium...
and i guess it's just perimeter

Comment: There are missing information for figures a and b.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the left edge of A and the top and right edges of B are supposed to go on to infinity.

Comment: Also the coloration suggests you need the **area**, not the perimeter.  This is further reinforced by the kinds of things it's asking you to build: A and D are a lot harder as just perimeters.

Answer (score 0):

for D, you have $\left(|z-a-ai| \le b\right) \cap \left(\Im(z) \ge a\right)$.  This use of intersections allows you to composite several shapes together (in this case a circle and a half-plane) to create your shape.  You'll need this for A as well, though I'll let you do that one.

For B, there's a neat trick that lets you pretend you're working in 2d vector space instead of the complex plane: given two complex numbers $u$ and $v$, you can find the dot product and 2d scalar analogue to 3d vector cross product of *vectors* $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ as $$\vec u \cdot \vec v = \Re\left(uv^*\right)$$ $$\vec u \times \vec v = \Im\left(uv^*\right)$$

Since a line (and thus, using an inequality, a half plane) can be expressed as an equation involving dot product, you can thus express B as such.